# How to ignore the background when runing a simulation using karate-gatling

Tags: karate

I want to run performance test on my APIs, the problem is every test feature is linked with a background that I use to generate my Bearer Token, and I don't want to run the simulation test on that background

I tried to tag my background and then modify my scala simulation in this way but it does not work :

```
import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class PerformanceTest extends Simulation {

  val test = scenario("test").exec(karateFeature("classpath","~@ignorebackground"))

  setUp(
    test.inject(rampUsers(2) during (5 seconds))
  )

}
```

And this is my feature test file :

```
Feature: Give information about computers

  @ignorebackground
  Background: Sample test
    Given url 'http://computer-database.gatling.io/computers'
    And param f = 'macbook'
    When method get
    Then status 200

  Scenario: Sample test
    Given url 'http://computer-database.gatling.io/computers'
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

Does this mean we can't tag a background step ? we can only tag features and scenarios ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you cannot tag the `Background`!

My suggestion is don't solve this using tags. This is what being able to switch variable values using `karate-config.js` is designed for. What I would do is have a [`karate.env`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#switching-the-environment) called `perf` and set a global flag e.g. `perfMode: true`.

Then you can do this in your `Background`:

```
Background:
* if (!perfMode) karate.callSingle('auth.feature')
```

And you can put your bearer token logic in `auth.feature` and properly re-use it in all features. In fact you should consider having this conditional logic in `karate-config.js` itself.

Refer the docs also: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#karatecallsingle

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer I'll check that and try to work with it !